# Merge Cell values with PHPExcel - PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have a simple table like:

```
- id 
- first_name
- last_name
- email
- phone
```

I'm using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to export my data in XLS format

```
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
   }
```

Now I want to merge the two fields `first_name` & `last_name` in one Cell

I tried:

```
$rowNumber = 1;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber,$row['id'])
                                 ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber,$row['first_name'])
                                 ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber,$row['last_name']);                                                                  
   $rowNumber++;
}
```

But I get errors and don't works. Any help?

Comment: Jared Farrish >> something like: http://dpaste.de/uXbH/raw/

Comment: It looks like your headers aren't working. Make sure they are before any output whatsoever (even whitespace).

Comment: If you have Firebug or Chrome, you can also use the NET tab to inspect the headers that your browser is seeing. But from what that looks like, your browser seems to think it's plaintext and is trying to display it like a plaintext document.

Answer (score 114):

There is a specific method to do this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');
```

You can also use:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:C1');
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Jahmic, I want to check whether two rows have been merged or not. I have 1000 of rows and if any two is merged in between then exit. Please can you help?

Comment: @user3816325 I haven't used these methods for a few years now, but I have no reason to believe anything is different.  Make backups and give it a go.  If your question is more complex, perhaps posting a new question is the way to go.

Comment: It works fine, but the value is gone, how to keep the cell values after merging?

Comment: @AnjanBiswas I haven't used this in quite a while, but I would suggest manually copying the values into separate PHP variables, format them the way you want, and then add that value back into the merged cell.  BTW, the same thing will happen if you merge cells using the actual Excel application. So, by design.

Comment: @Jahmic I already found the solution. Actually I used cell merging for bar chart. To add value = `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "2010");` cell merging =  
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A5');` horizontal and vertical alignment for the cell =
`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:A5')
    ->getAlignment()
 ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:A5')
    ->getAlignment()
 ->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);`

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');
```

Answer (score 4):

`$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells("A".($p).":B".($p));`
for dynamic merging of cells