# PHPExcel Values get remove on merge row

Tags: php, excel, row, cell, phpexcel

In my application, I have a json file which holds products.
In a loop I loop through every item and put them in cells.

```php
$this->row = 4;
foreach ($this->json['products'] as $product) {
    $this->template->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $this->row, $product);
    $this->row++;
}
```

Afterwards, I am setting the style of the excel file

```php
$this->template->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J6:K6');
```

Basically merging row `J` and `K` with each other but because of this the value of `K` gets removed. How can I set the value of `K` to the next row value dynamically after the merge of an inaccessible row?

Answer (score 1):

@jahmic gives answer here

```
//There is a specific method to do this:

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('J6:K6');
//You can also use:

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('J6:K6');
//That should do the trick.
```

> Link is
>   [Merge Cell values with PHPExcel - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820250/merge-cell-values-with-phpexcel-php)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want the 2 merged values in the same row. I want the second value in the row to the right of it. So I dont want to merge the values but rather put the second value in a row next to the merged rows.